# Speed Suddenly jumps from zero to Infinity

Tags: android, location

I am currently attempting to work out the speed of a person using an app.

I think the Location Update is bugged, because when I am sitting still, it detects that the speed is zero or around about 0, then suddenly jumps to infinity for some reason (Yes, the app displays 'Infinity'), and then back down to 0.

I think it has something to do with attempting to divide by zero, though I am not sure why.

This is my code: onConnected:

```
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        OldLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mLocationClient);
    }
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    int ExceedInstance = PhoneBelt.getExceedInstance();

    int ExceedingLimitInteger = PhoneBelt.getExceedInt();

    float Distance = OldLocation.distanceTo(location);

    long TimeDiff = location.getTime()-OldLocation.getTime();

    long SecondDiff = TimeDiff/1000 % 6;

    float Speed = Distance/SecondDiff;
}
```

**Why does the speed suddenly and randomly jump to Infinity?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it can be caused, because long SecondDiff can be 0. Finally Distance will be divided 0 and it will cause speed=infinity.

Comment: That's strange, because the second difference cannot be zero... the minimum update interval is set to 5 seconds.

Comment: what about  %6? I can make expression 0.

Comment: Oh... huh. I'll have to fix that one. Thanks for pointing this out!